# Prediction/Classification within each grup (Multi-Class / Multi-Label)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling

I would like to make a prediction of a list of products (>1000 in dataset) within a particular product category (>100 in dataset).

**Example:**

1. Select product categories (1 or many): fruits, vegetables or more;
2. Model makes predictions and possibly return:

- Fruits: Banana, Apple, Strawberry;
- Vegetables: Carrot, Onion, Potato;

**Assumptions:**

- Product category/categories to be entered by the user and prediction will happen within this group or groups (it is important to return all of them in the results);

**Potential solution:**

- Regarding products classification I take into consideration Multi-Class Classification (One vs Rest or One vs One => however, I am afraid that it will required way to much computing power and time)
- **The tricky part is to make prediction within a category, does it means that I need to build a separate model for each category**?

Comment: "it is important to return all of them in the results"  Is this means returning all products in same category?

Comment: What model does seems like just to predict elements from subcategories. In that case you just need to train 1 model for this.  Please share your datatable format example to make it more clear

Comment: Thank you @EnesKuz -> I post data and description in the main answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Below is some sample data limited to few examples only out of >1000. First picture is a colored print-screen of a table to highlight different categories: main, macro-, micro-categories & below the picture is a raw data.
The objective is:

1. User enters two (can be one or even all) macro-categories (e.g. Citrus and Leafy green)
2. For these macro-categories (which were entered) the model returns top best matches
3. I am afraid that if I train a model (RF or SVM) over whole dataset, using macr- and micro-categories as different features in the model -> the model could predict micro-category not related to the macro-category (e.g. I will get as a result Oranges (Citrus), but I entered to the model only Berries and Melons).

[image]

| Main_class | Macro_class | Micro_class | Performance | Usage | Experience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruits | Berries | Blueberries | 1 | 0.5 | 6.05 |
| Fruits | Berries | Raspberries | 2 | 1 | 12.1 |
| Fruits | Berries | Goji berries | 3 | 1.5 | 18.15 |
| Fruits | Berries | Strawberries | 4 | 2 | 24.2 |
| Fruits | Berries | Bilberries | 5 | 2.5 | 30.25 |
| Fruits | Berries | Açaí berries | 6 | 3 | 36.3 |
| Fruits | Berries | Cranberries | 7 | 3.5 | 42.35 |
| Fruits | Berries | Grapes | 8 | 4 | 48.4 |
| Fruits | Citrus | oranges | 21 | 10.5 | 127.05 |
| Fruits | Citrus | grapefruits | 23 | 11.5 | 139.15 |
| Fruits | Citrus | mandarins | 25 | 12.5 | 151.25 |
| Fruits | Citrus | limes | 27 | 13.5 | 163.35 |
| Fruits | Stone fruit | nectarines | 6 | 3 | 36.3 |
| Fruits | Stone fruit | apricots | 7 | 3.5 | 42.35 |
| Fruits | Stone fruit | peaches | 8 | 4 | 48.4 |
| Fruits | Stone fruit | plums | 9 | 4.5 | 54.45 |
| Fruits | Melons | watermelons | 2 | 1 | 12.1 |
| Fruits | Melons | rockmelons | 3 | 1.5 | 18.15 |
| Fruits | Melons | honeydew melons | 4 | 2 | 24.2 |
| Vegetables | Leafy green | lettuce | 25 | 12.5 | 151.25 |
| Vegetables | Leafy green | spinach | 27 | 13.5 | 163.35 |
| Vegetables | Leafy green | silverbeet | 6 | 3 | 36.3 |
| Vegetables | Cruciferous | cabbage | 7 | 3.5 | 42.35 |
| Vegetables | Cruciferous | cauliflower | 8 | 4 | 48.4 |
| Vegetables | Cruciferous | Brussels sprouts | 25 | 12.5 | 151.25 |
| Vegetables | Cruciferous | broccoli | 27 | 13.5 | 163.35 |
| Vegetables | Marrow | pumpkin | 6 | 3 | 36.3 |
| Vegetables | Marrow | cucumber | 7 | 3.5 | 42.35 |
| Vegetables | Marrow | zucchini | 8 | 4 | 48.4 |
| Vegetables | Allium | onion | 5 | 2.5 | 30.25 |
| Vegetables | Allium | garlic | 6 | 3 | 36.3 |
| Vegetables | Allium | shallot | 7 | 3.5 | 42.35 |

Comment: please explain "model returns top best matches" what is that mean ?

Comment: Also as I see  you dont need main class at all.  And you are right you shouldnt train your network mixing micro and macros.

Comment: "model returns top best matches" -> I assume that model will predict 2 dependent variables: micro_class and performance. By predicting performance I would get numerical information (performance) to make products ranking and get for example top 3 'best matches'. Also, to predict micro_class I would probably need to funnel dataset and create separate classifier for each macro_category?