# Each multi-class output has another level of multi-class output

Tags: nlp, multiclass-classification, multitask-learning

I want to predict a major class and then minor class.
Major class is a multi-class model which has 4 categories. Each of this categories has 10-15 subcategories, for which I can build a multi-task model with 4 heads. Is there a better architecture?

I am worried that if I build a supervised model to predict the subcategories directly, i.e., a model with ~100 labels, the classes will be confusing and the model will not be able to classify accurately. However, I am hesitant to build models per category as its not scalable and adds operational overhead.

Similar to this - [Prediction/Classification within each grup (Multi-Class / Multi-Label)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/105076/)